# how to make changes permanently to css elements with -moz-transform?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
        var transform = ['scale(' + scale + ')'];
        $.merge(transform, ['rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)']);
        $(this).css(-moz-transform, transform.join(' '));
```

this block of code executes when an event is generated , the new scaling and rotation is added to css element,but whenever the same event is generated again the css element resets itself to the original size and position .The transformation is carried out after resetting during the second time.I want to eliminate the resetting of the element to original size and position.How can i make the change permanent in the first time when event is fired ,and build on it when the event is fired the second time?
Please help thanks in advance

Comment: How are you setting 'scale' and 'rotate'?

Comment: scale and rotate just has numeric values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this code, but keep in mind you're setting `scale` and `rotate` in absolute terms, not relative to its 'initial' state.

So each time this code executes, the `-moz-transform` property of your element is being overwritten.  If you want to rotate and scale it based on it's current state, you'll have to keep track of your `scale` and `rotate` values and adjust them as necessary.  e.g., if this code is in a loop, you can do `rotate=rotate+5;` or something like that.

You can also request these properties from the CSS using `($this).css('-moz-transform')`, parse that to get the values you want, and update `scale` and `rotate` accordingly.

Comment: @Jeff, Thanks ,i understood my mistake but can you explain more on how to get the values using  ($this).css('-moz-transform') and parse it ?

Comment: Well, I stand corrected.  For most properties, you can do something like $(this).css('width') to return the width (e.g., "50px"), and you could simply chop off the 'px' and use that to increment your variable.  However, when you ask for -moz-transform, FF returns a weird matrix representation which isn't easily parsable.  I think this is just a bug because it is an "experimental" CSS property.  That being the case, I would follow my first suggestion and just keep track of 'scale' and 'rotate' each time you set them by storing them as global JS variables.

Comment: This is not a bug - this is the transform matrix and it's what you're supposed to get according to the spec. You have to do your own matrix math to decompose the matrix into component values like scale, rotate and skew

Comment: @Jeff,is there a way to set -moz-transform or -webkit-transform to relative position,instead of absolute,i mean without using the global js variables?

Comment: @Sai There's no solution inherent in the CSS markup itself.  But there's probably a jQuery plugin that will do it.  How about something like http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html ?  This should allow you to set the scale as $(this).scale($(this).scale()+1.5) or something